# How do I set a value in one method and then return that value to another method?

Tags: c#, methods, converters

I need some help. If I understand this right, the value of "int F" gets sent to "FtoC" converted and then returned to the MenuSelect1 method.
Now I want to return or save the value "int C" has after its been converted to the MenuSelect2 method? I have tried everything I can think of, but I just get errors. (I have reset the code to original state now where MenuSelect1 and 2 är void). Whats an easy way to solve this? Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


  public static class SecondClass {


  public static int FtoC(int fahrenheit)
  {
    int C = ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
    return C;
  }

  
  public static void MenuSelect1()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      int F = 0;
      Console.Write("\nType how many degrees Fahrenheit you want: ");

      try
      {
        F = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      }
      
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
      }

      int C = SecondClass.FtoC(F);

      if (C < 80 || C > 87)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Try a different temperature.");
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine(C + "°C is perfect. Start the sauna and enjoy!");
        break;
      }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
  }

   
  public static void MenuSelect2()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Starting Sauna. Wait for it to reach desired temperature...");
    Console.Write("Temperature: {0}");
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
    

}
```

Comment: As the class is static, you cant keep a value because you can't instantiate it. so the only way is make MenuSelect1 return int C's value and keep that value in a callers variable, then calll MenuSelect2 with said value changin it's signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also save the value of `C` as a property / field in your class. Here is an example of saving it as a field called `_celcius`:

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


  public static class SecondClass {

  private static int _celcius = 0;  // <--- Your field

  public static int FtoC(int fahrenheit)
  {
    int C = ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
    return C;
  }

  
  public static void MenuSelect1()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      int F = 0;
      Console.Write("\nType how many degrees Fahrenheit you want: ");

      try
      {
        F = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      }
      
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
      }

      _celcius = SecondClass.FtoC(F);   // <--- Assign field here

      if (_celcius  < 80 || _celcius  > 87)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Try a different temperature.");
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine(_celcius + "°C is perfect. Start the sauna and enjoy!");
        break;
      }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
  }

   
  public static void MenuSelect2()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Starting Sauna. Wait for it to reach desired temperature...");
    Console.Write("Temperature: {0}", _celcius); // <--- Use your field here
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
    

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You either call the `MenuSelect2()` directly from the `MenuSelect1()`

```
public static void MenuSelect1()
{
    while (true)
    {
      int F = 0;
      Console.Write("\nType how many degrees Fahrenheit you want: ");

      try
      {
        F = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      }
      
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
      }

      int C = SecondClass.FtoC(F);

      if (C < 80 || C > 87)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Try a different temperature.");
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine(C + "°C is perfect. Start the sauna and enjoy!");
        
        // here
        MenuSelect2(C);
        
        break;
      }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();

}

public static void MenuSelect2(int C)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting Sauna. Wait for it to reach desired temperature...");
    Console.Write($"Temperature: {C}");   // <- notice the $ for interpolated strings.
}
```

---

Or return the value from the `MainSelect1()` to the caller which calls the `MainSelect2()` method.

```
public static void Main()
{
    // get the temperature
    int C = MenuSelect1();

    // pass it to the other method.
    MenuSelect2(C);

    Console.ReadKey();
}


public static int MenuSelect1()  // <- change the signature (return int)
{
    while (true)
    {
      int F = 0;
      Console.Write("\nType how many degrees Fahrenheit you want: ");

      try
      {
        F = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
      }
      
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
      }

      int C = SecondClass.FtoC(F);

      if (C < 80 || C > 87)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Try a different temperature.");
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine(C + "°C is perfect. Start the sauna and enjoy!");
        
        return C; // return the value to the caller.
      }
    }
}

public static void MenuSelect2(int C)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting Sauna. Wait for it to reach desired temperature...");
    Console.Write($"Temperature: {C}");   // <- notice the $ for interpolated strings.
}
```

I rather use the second suggestion, because this way the `MenuSelect1()` isn't tightcoupled to `MenuSelect2()` and can be reused for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem at this point is that the variable C is instantiated and stored inside the method MenuSelect1(), what you should do is create a class variable like `int fahrenheitValue` and then inside the menuSelect1 method use `this.fahrenheitValue = C` so the value is stored inside the class variable and then you can access it from everywhere

Comment: No while the class is static

Comment: I missed to say that the 'this.fahrenheitValue = C' is to be put just after you call the method FtoC in the MenuSelect1()

Comment: @J.Salas you're right, so to do this he should at least remove the static tag from MenuSelect1() and MenuSelect2(), but in that case he needs to ponderate if he needs those classes to stay static like this

Answer (score 0):

All the variables that are defined in MenuSelect1() will NOT be visible as soon as the method ends.

You can define a static property in your "SecondClass"

```
private static int degreesCelsius;
```

Then you can set this property in

```
if (C < 80 || C > 87)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Try a different temperature.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(C + "°C is perfect. Start the sauna and enjoy!");
    degreesCelsius = C;
    break;
}
```

In your MenuSelect2() method you can use it.

```
Console.Write("Temperature: {0}", degreesCelsius);
```